# active_admin - show pg - linking to other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, activeadmin

I need to have links to several other models within the show page of the work order model.

1. WorkOrder parent
2. CountyCriminal - child
3. CaptureAll - child
4. etc....

The code below is working, but I feel like there is a better way?  Here is the code:

```
panel "Screening Tasks" do
        table_for work_order.county_criminals do |t|
          t.column{ |item| link_to item.title, admin_county_criminal_path(item)}   
        end
        table_for work_order.capture_alls do |t|
          t.column{ |item| link_to item.title, admin_capture_all_path(item)}   
        end
      end
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "there is a better way", are you referring to the fact that you are having to repeat your table_for on each of the child models?  You could probably clean this up by creating some dynamic ruby based on the list of child models, but unless this is a recurring problem, I'm not convinced that this is a good use of time.

Comment: Yes, in line with the DRY methodology... Since I am new to rails, I was not sure how to address this issue.  I know there will be more than 15 models, so my current code is not very efficient.  Thanks for your suggestions, not sure I understand "the good use of time" statement? Are you saying this is not place for my question?

Comment: No - your question is excellent.  The issue is whether this is a sufficiently recurring problem for you to take deep steps to solve it (trying to dynamically figure out what other models need to show up and displaying these vs. simply having an array with model names that you iterate through with an eval to create the code for you).  I'd lean towards the latter, though it adds some maintenance requirements should you have additional tables that you need to add.  It feels like you could have `%w(county_criminal capture_all etc) each do` and then simply do an `eval` to generate your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response Marc!  At this point, since the code does work, I am going to move on.  I will take a look into implementing the code you suggestion.  Best!